# Launch Mac Application on Event day by Terminal

Tags: javascript, macos, events, terminal, scheduled-tasks

i have an task to create event on particular day and time i have to open any sample application automatically so far i done created an event on date and time but i dono how to add script to launch application

**here my sample code:**

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iCal" to make new event at end of calendar 1 with properties {start date:date "12, 19, 2016 1:02:00 PM", summary:"Demo"}'
```

**here is another code which i found to open any Application in single command :**

```
open -a iTunes
```

The above code which is tested on Terminal and Event is created on calendar

Now what i actually Need this is it possible to combine this two script in single command and Test it ?(i.e on particular date i want to launch my App automatically)

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to create a "open file alarm" with the path to some Applescript that opens the application:

```
tell application "iCal"
   tell calendar "My Calendar"
      set theEvent to event 1
      set theDate to (current date) - 3 * days
      tell theEvent
         make new open file alarm at end with properties {trigger date:theDate, 
            filepath:theFile}
      end tell
   end tell
end tell
```

See [example](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.11/ScriptingiCal/index.html) .